# Facebook Unity SDK : Where is TESTING Facebook Access Token and ID Fields in FBSettings

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I get started with facebook unity SDK but I can't find TESTING Facebook access token and ID likes in tutorial on step 6. Anyone found its? 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/getting-started/

Comment: I cant see any `Facebook access token` in the step 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an old screenshot and the docs need to be updated, I'm sorry for the confusion. Task filed, should be fixed soon.

Comment: In fact, the docs have been updated! OP, thanks again for the sharp eyes.

Answer (score 0):

See the screenshot in Step-2 ; there are fields: `App ID` and `App Secret`

Comment: On step 6 below FB.init(), You will found it

Comment: That's the user id and token; that thing is not required- Optional. That are just for the unity editor (not for actual implementation). If you still want to use them, you can get them from http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer . `ID` is your fb id and `token` is your access token. PS. don't forget to accept the ans if helped!